# Redirect apex domain to www using route53 alias record not working

Tags: redirect, amazon-route53

I had my example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) pointed to the same IP 111.222.333.444 in AWS route53 via A records.

Now I want to redirect example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) .

In route53 I changed example.com A record to an alias record, “Alias to another record in this hosted zone”. Then in the next field I selected [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
After 24 hours, I can still access http://example.com.  It is not redirected to http://www.example.com.